# Building dynamic configuration paths in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration

I have an external configuration with keys that changes depending on what environment im in. I need to be able to do something like this:

application.yml

```
external_val: ${${LOCAL_ENV_VAR}-external-path}
```

That is first I need to use the environment variables to substitute a path for the external source, then I need this path the be resolved in the external configuration source.

The only thing I can get working is hard coding the values as such:

application.yml

```
external_val: ${preprod-external-path}
```

What is the appropriate way of doing nested properties lookup in Spring Boot?

Comment: I assume you already studied [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-externalize-configuration)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing it like this :

```
external_val: ${${LOCAL_ENV_VAR}-external-path}
```

you can split it into 2 properties, like :

```
local_env_var_external_path: ${LOCAL_ENV_VAR}-external-path
external_val: ${local_env_var}
```